# cannot resolve symbol [.close(); .println(); etc.] after indexing(updating indices) IntelliJ 14

Tags: java, indexing, intellij-idea, import, cannot-find-symbol

after opening ***intellij 14 ide for MAC***, and it starts to reindexing the project, once its finished the methods such as .close(); or .println(); turns to red. i have tried every possible i could find at forums and here, and **"invalidate caches/restart"** did solve the problem but only until it reindexes the project. i have deleted the .idea folder and the .iml file, rebuilt the project from ground, reinstalled scale plugin etc. Nothing has worked permanently.

Recommendations from comments that I have tried:

- I have set the SDK for 1.6
- I have cleaned up all files and directories and reinstalled IntelliJ but     Still have the same problem.

Some help please!

Comment: Did you set a project SDK?

Comment: Try and remove the system/ directory in $HOME/.IntellijIdea14 then start the IDE again

Comment: i have cleaned up all files and directories and reinstalled IntelliJ but Still have the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely sounds like your JDK is not set up.

Go to `Project Structure` (Ctrl + Alt + Shift + S)

Under `Project Settings`, go to `Project`, and verify `Project SDK` is set up, and *correct*. Try an alternate JDK, if you like, just to be sure the one selected is not corrupt or incorrect, although it should usually be red if it is missing.

Comment: Are you sure none of the core java libraries are included as project libraries in your project? can you describe more about the project strucutre, particularly with libs and dependencies?